# Persistence Ignorance and REST

Tags: rest, testing, design-patterns, persistence, web-oriented-architecture

**Persistence Ignorance** (PI) is a key guideline to achieve efficient functional testing. I believe it should apply to infrastructural purposes in general. However, it seems this guideline is rarely followed in **Web-oriented architecture** (WOA), especially with **REST** APIs. As REST seems to be a data-centric architecture, I do not understand why PI does not apply to WOA in a more popular manner, to prevent systematic and expensive end-to-end testing.

Is there any kind of architecture or practice that could ease the introduction of PI into REST architectures ? Based on your experience, did you try to follow the PI principle in your REST architectures ? If not, why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all a question of layers and abstraction.  There's no need for a REST end point to have any knowledge of where or how data is persisted under the covers.  The persistence mechanism can be injected or swapped out at run time.  The end point should only know enough to translate the API call parameters into whatever the next layer down is expecting (if needed). Admittedly, many REST implementations load up the end point with persistence knowledge, but that's not a problem confined to RESTful APIs.

A little bit of the D in [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) can be used to introduce PI to a RESTful end point.

Using a WebAPI example, the Controller (end point) only knows about the **interface** of the next layer.  For testing purposes that layer can be mocked to isolate testing to the API itself. The next layer down can be the persistence layer or a service layer if more complicated logic or access to multiple repositories is required.

```cs
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    //controller only knows about the interface to the next layer down
    private readonly IServiceOrRepositoryLayer _serviceOrRepo;

    //persistence or service layer injected into the constructor
    //useful for testing
    //could also inject a factory if more flexibility needed at runtime
    public ValuesController(IServiceOrRepositoryLayer serviceOrRepo)
    {
        _serviceOrRepo = serviceOrRepo;
    }

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<SomePOCO> Get()
    {
        return _serviceOrRepo.ListAll();
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public SomePOCO Get(int id)
    {
        return _serviceOrRepo.Get(id);
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post(SomePOCO value)
    {
        //can either pass the value directly or transform it here 
        //to what the next layer needs
        _serviceOrRepo.Create(value);
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, SomePOCO value)
    {
         _serviceOrRepo.Update(value, id);
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        _serviceOrRepo.Delete(id);
    }
}
```